# For the infinite limit, why can't use the estimate value?

Tags: calculus, limits

I understand this question may sound stupid but it confused me.

For the following, $\lim_{x\to {-\infty}}\sqrt{4x^2+2x}+2x $

I tried to use $2x\cdot 2x$ to substitute $2x(2x+1)$ because $x$ is approaching $-\infty$, then my answer was $0$ but the actual answer is $-\frac{1}{2}$. I was so confused where I was wrong.

Comment: @AlvinL I thought after the substitution I will get $-2x+2x=0$?

Comment: Generally speaking, making invalid substitutions is a bad idea. There's a fundamental logical principle here: from a statement that is known to be false, there are no valid conclusions. Perhaps you might wish to claim *this substitution does not affect the answer*; in which case, now you know that's wrong.

Comment: @LeeMosher yes this post helps a lot! Thanks